# TDD with Enzyme shallow and mount?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

When I render a component using `shallow` or `mount`, the component is rendered in memory and is not attached to DOM.

This means that, while I run my tests, I don't actually see any output in the browser.

How am I supposed to do Test Driven Development if I can't see if the component I'm developing looks as it should? (css style, sizes etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your component to be rendered an mounted une the "browser", than use the render() method of Enzyme. Be sure to have a window available (see jsdom to fake a window). But IMO, you should be able to do all of your test with shallow or mount, the API is nice

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm doing TDT I create my whole component using just the tests I create for it, and I think I should have the chance to see what am I building... It would be just impossible to develop a button without knowing how it looks.

Comment: Hmmm, in this case you cannot fake a dom window. You should run your test "in browser" mode, to be able to inspect JS our CSS as you want

Comment: Oh ok, I just remember this project about cloning Yelp, including the testing part https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/react-tutorial-cloning-yelp/#configuring-testing, enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

> How am I supposed to do Test Driven Development if I can't see if the
>   component I'm developing looks as it should? (css style, sizes etc)

The purpose of Enzyme is not visual regression test, for that you will have to use tools like PhantomJS, related article https://css-tricks.com/visual-regression-testing-with-phantomcss/

You can achieve some kind of styling testing by checking if your component has the right selectors when they are rendered. e.g.

```
it( 'should add the "selected" class when a click happend to one of the Elements', () => {
    const wrapper = mount( <Elements /> );

    const option = wrapper.find( 'h5' );
    expect( option.hasClass( 'selected' ) ).to.equal( false );
    option.simulate( 'click' );
    expect( option.hasClass( 'selected' ) ).to.equal( true );
} );
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to test the style, I just want to see my component while I write it.

Comment: @Avraam Mavridis : I'm trying to test login functionality by using **shallow** api. But seems like not working. Is it not possible to test the functionalities in enzyme+mocha ?